# Force applied between neighboring atoms resulting in increase in separation

Tags: thermodynamics

I am attempting a past paper question in practice for an upcoming exam and I am a little lost with the following question:

*Using lennard Jones model for potential.*
An external force $F$ is applied to a pair of neighboring atoms in a solid, which results in an increase in their separation by a distance $\Delta r$. Show that for small values of $\Delta r$,

$$\Delta r = \frac{ F}{(\frac{d^2U}{dr^2})_{r=a_0}}$$

I am a little lost because I am failing to get anywhere near the answer - Using ideas of force gives you a first order differential, using the formula for a differential was of no additional help because I still fail to have a second order differential. I am confused where the second order is coming from as if I actually do the differential and try to substitute in I have many more terms. I could try an expansion but I still have terms of $a_0$ which do not cancel.
 If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated

Comment: Try rearranging the Taylor expansion for $U(a_0+\Delta r)$.

Comment: @lemon - Thanks for the idea, I will give it a go now

Answer (score 0):

$$F\delta r=\delta U = U(a_0+\delta r)-U(a_0)$$
Use Taylor expansion and remember that $U^\prime (a_0)=0$ at the stable position (minimum potential).
$$F\delta r=\frac {U^{''}(a_0)}2{{\delta r}^2} + o({\delta r}^2)$$
Thus, $$\delta r = \frac {2F}{U^{''}(a_0)}$$
There is a factor of 2 missing in your question.